# Every character I type in Word 2011 (Mac) gets written two places

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I somehow toggled a switch in Word 2011, which makes every key I press appear both at the position of the cursor and at the end of the sentence.

If I had this sentence (| = cursor position):

```
Foo bar| baz qux.
```

And I type `hello world`, the result would be:

```
Foo bar hello world bax qux. hello world
```

The text disappears when changing the position of the cursor with either the mouse or the arrow keys.

It also appears to only affect one section of my document.

How can I toggle this off again?